# How to remove certain lines from XML where byte size is higher then 62914560 B?

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I generated an XML of a complete list of files the lines look like below.

```
<file name="mail.MSG" bytesSize="42167" />
```

The XML file contains a lot of files larger then 60MB which I don't want in this file. I know that I can bookmark certain lines and remove them after. But I think I also need some regex to solve the issue here. I don't know much about regex so I have no clue how to construct them. Someone who can help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: I tried below regex code  in notepad++ using the bookmark principle. I thought that is was working till I saw the comment by you. During my test it gave me multiple lines larger than 60mb.

Comment: Eventually I changed it to this:

.*bytesSize="(\s*[1-9]\d{8,}|[6-9][2-9][0-9]{6}|[7-9][0-9]{7}\s*)".*

Comment: Have a try with: `bytesSize="\h*(?:[1-9]\d{8,}|[7-9]\d{7}|6[3-9]\d{6})\h*"` the limit is `63000000`, if you really want `62914560` the regex will be longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so sure if it would be the best way, I'm guessing that you might want to design multiple expressions, depending on the numerical ranges that you might have, such as:

```
.*bytesSize="\s*[6-9]\d{7}\s*".*
```

for instance, which would find ~60000000 to ~99999999, then replace it with an empty string.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p8WzNa/1/)

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XGAprN/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/XGAprN/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: This will only work, of course, if the XML is formatted in precisely the same way as your example (e.g. with double-quotes around the attribute value and no extraneous whitespace.). Don't put such a solution into production and expect it still to work next year: for a robust solution, use XSLT.